# xcode uiimageview background image

Tags: ios, uiimageview, background-image

I am relatively new to Obj-C so thanks in advance.

I have a UIImageView on the storyboard. I have a Tap Gesture Recognizer over it. When the user taps, the choose/take photo option comes up and the image view is correctly updated with the photo. What I want to do is have the UIImageView have a camera icon png in it until the user chooses the photo.

Comment: Are you saving the image which are selected from camera roll. IF you are saving then you can check wether there is saved file or not if no saved file then show camera icon in UIImageView otherwise show saved image.

Comment: Thanks Shashi. How would I check to see if the photo is a saved file?

Comment: This works but not I am sending the icon in the JSON file that I'm uploading. Is there just a way to apply a background image to UIImageView or some other way? thanks again

Comment: I am not following you. Can describe all the steps? It seems easy fix

Comment: Never mind Shashi, I used your original logic and got it working. Thank you so much. I wish there was a way to give you a point.

Comment: I have posted my logic as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1

saving the image to Document Director which selected from camera roll.

Step 2

When you are saving then you can check wether there is saved file or not
if no saved file then show camera icon in UIImageView otherwise show saved image

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote, as I said, I just started. I did give it  a check. Is that enough?